# How to use two or more openvpn clients at the same time?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I want to connect to several ip at the same time, for this I use the VPN Gate service and I have, for example, two configs.

```
dev tun0
;dev tap0
proto tcp
remote 211.127.50.206 1603
;http-proxy-retry
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port]
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA1
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
client
verb 3
```

and

```
dev tun1
;dev tap1
proto tcp
remote 219.100.37.24 443
;http-proxy-retry
;http-proxy [proxy server] [proxy port]
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA1
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
client
verb 3
```

The problem is that the traffic of the second vpn goes through the first open vpn.

Comment: The main problem is related to routing you should check what routes push the server to the client. It's necessary show the routing tables pushed to the client when you connect both VPNs

Comment: 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.234.11.250 dev tun1 
10.211.1.14 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.211.1.13 
10.234.11.250 dev tun1 proto kernel scope link src 10.234.11.249 
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.234.11.250 dev tun1

Comment: Why don't explicitly write routing commands in client openvpn config files?

Comment: @GeorgeY I do not understand which ip subnets other than 128.0.0.0/1 and 0.0.0.0/1 can still be used

Comment: 128.0.0.0/1 and 0.0.0.0/1 = anywhere except for 127.0.0.1. So if you assign one openvpn client to route all the outgoing traffic like this, what is the point then to use another openvpn client? If you want each of them to bear half of the outgoing traffic, assign one to route 0.0.0.0/1 and the other to route 128.0.0.0/1.